# I'm unable to plot a backtest of my algorithm

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, back-testing

Thank you in advance for any help!

I'm trying to backtest a very simple moving average cross over strategy in Python. I'm using the Jupyter notebook.

I've installed and imported backtrader and matplotlib. However, I'm unable to plot anything and I can't figure out this bug :/

I'm a fairly successful trader but am new to python. Thank you for your help!

[image: First half of my code!]
[image: Second half of my code!]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is addressed in https://github.com/mementum/backtrader/pull/418 and this patch is the latest commit to master, but there hasn't been a release since 2019-05.

You can install the patched version like so:

```sh
pip install git+https://github.com/mementum/backtrader.git@0fa63ef4a35dc53cc7320813f8b15480c8f85517#egg=backtrader
```

You could alternatively specify the required commit in requirements.txt like so:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/mementum/backtrader.git@0fa63ef4a35dc53cc7320813f8b15480c8f85517#egg=backtrader
```

Comment: Run above lines in command and it should work :)